# UNION ALL define table

Tags: mysql, union

Can you please tell me how can I determine from which table this id is derived?
`SELECT id FROM table_1 UNION SELECT id FROM table_2`

```
table_1
|id|
|1 |
```

```
table_2
|id|
|2 |
```

Through while I got two id (1, 2). How to understand in which table id 1 and in which table id 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inject your own identifier, such as:

```
SELECT id, 'T1' as Source
FROM table_1 
UNION 
SELECT id, 'T2'
FROM table_2
```

Comment: Normally, when using UNION, you will end up with one row if table_1.id equals table_2.id. But since adding the `Source` column these duplicates will no longer be filtered, effectively resulting in a `UNION ALL`

Comment: Yes granted that's true - it would also conflict with the OPs implied requirements, with 1 row deduped from both tables, which table is the value from. I suppose it depends on if this works in the required scenario.

Comment: I created a fiddle, which might give some more info, and a possible work-around (to ALL ): [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84d0b98a80478310c9ef39f7eb999427)   (P.S. It's only a possible work-arounde, because of assuming things that are not 100% clear from the original question)